# NextJS React - WebpackError: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to playing around with React.
I followed the "Getting Started" tutorial of NextJs ([link](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started)) and I have successfully created the new project.

As soon as I try to import third-party plugins like [current-devices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/current-device) or [smooth-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smooth-scrollbar) I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
(anonymous function)
/c/xampp/htdocs/nextjs/node_modules/smooth-scrollbar/dist/smooth-scrollbar.js:1:262
Module._compile
module.js:652:30
Module._extensions..js
module.js:663:10
Module.load
module.js:565:32
tryModuleLoad
module.js:505:12
Function.Module._load
module.js:497:3
Module.require
module.js:596:17
require
internal/module.js:11:18
smooth-scrollbar
webpack:/external "smooth-scrollbar":1
> 1 | module.exports = require("smooth-scrollbar");
View compiled
__webpack_require__
./webpack/bootstrap:21
  18 | // Execute the module function
  19 | var threw = true;
  20 | try {
> 21 |  modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
     | ^  22 |  threw = false;
  23 | } finally {
  24 |  if(threw) delete installedModules[moduleId];
View compiled
Module../pages/index.js
/_next/development/server/static/development/pages/index.js:221:74
__webpack_require__
./webpack/bootstrap:21
  18 | // Execute the module function
  19 | var threw = true;
  20 | try {
> 21 |  modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
     | ^  22 |  threw = false;
  23 | } finally {
  24 |  if(threw) delete installedModules[moduleId];
View compiled
3
/_next/development/server/static/development/pages/index.js:383:18
__webpack_require__
./webpack/bootstrap:21
  18 | // Execute the module function
  19 | var threw = true;
  20 | try {
> 21 |  modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
     | ^  22 |  threw = false;
  23 | } finally {
  24 |  if(threw) delete installedModules[moduleId];
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
```

The import I made in the file C:\xampp\htdocs\nextjs\pages\index.js

is just:

```
import Scrollbar from 'smooth-scrollbar';
import device from 'current-device'
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Next.js has a server-side and a client-side,
window is not defined in server-side,'smooth-scrollbar' and 'current-device' probably use window both,
you can use dynamic import of next with `ssr: false` for just using some package in clinet-side:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('package'),
  { ssr: false }
)

// ...


// use it in render like:
<DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
```

for more info visit [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was not considering the server-side rendering and the client-side rendering!

Comment: Short, sweet, and works. Couldn't ask for more, thank you :)

Comment: @SamSverko Happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks so much, I have window location error sometimes and I didn't know why! It was simple and great!

Comment: great! your answer also worked for this error `Next.js SyntaxError "Unexpected token 'export'"`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65936222/3051080

Answer (score 5):

In my case, doing Nextjs Dynamic import was not enough.

**EXAMPLE**

**Imported TVChart.js Dynamically**

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"
import * as React from "react"

const TVChartContainer = dynamic(() => import("./TVChart"), { ssr: false })

export default () => {
  return <TVChartContainer />
}
```

If you are still getting  **> ReferenceError: window is not defined** error even after using [dynamic imports with no ssr](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) as mentioned in the accepted answer, then it might be due to the dependency which requiring ***window*** be present and is imported at the top level.

In my case I was importing TradingView Charting Library **widget** object like this:

**TVChart.js** - **Not working**

```
import { widget } from "../public/static/charting_library/charting_library.min" //did not work

class TVChart extends Component {

    tvWidget = null

    componentDidMount() {
        const widgetOptions = {} //ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions
        this.tvWidget = new widget(widgetOptions)
    }

    render() {
        <div id="tv_chart_container" className="TVChartContainer" />
    }
}
export default TVChart;
```

**TVChart.js - Working**

```
// import { widget } from "../public/static/charting_library/charting_library.min" // <-- Remove this line

class TVChart extends Component {

    tvWidget = null

    async componentDidMount() {
        const { widget } = await import("../public/static/charting_library/charting_library.min") // <-- Import asynchronously
        const widgetOptions = {} //ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions
        this.tvWidget = new widget(widgetOptions)
    }

    render() {
        <div id="tv_chart_container" className="TVChartContainer" />
    }

}
export default TVChart;
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: This was very helpful! Note that if you're importing an npm package, as I was, you can access the default export by destructuring it. You can event alias as something else: `const { default: LibName } = await import('SomeNPMLibrary');`