# WowJs React UseEffect

Tags: next.js, wow.js

```jsx
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import WOW from 'wowjs/dist/wow.js';
import React from 'react';
import '@/assets/styles/scss/main.scss';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const wow = () => {
            new WOW.WOW({
                boxClass: 'wow', // default
                animateClass: 'animated', // default
                offset: 0, // default
                mobile: true, // default
                live: true, // default
            });
        };
        // if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        //     return;
        // }
        wow.init();
        wow.call(window);
    }, []);
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

**Error Below**

Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
wowjs/dist/wow.js (1:0) @ eval

> 1 | module.exports = require("wowjs/dist/wow.js");
> Blockquote

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS React - WebpackError: window is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60738486/nextjs-react-webpackerror-window-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I am seeing in your post, the issue is with the `wow.js` package itself rather than in your code.  The `useEffect` only gets executed on the client side so accessing `window` there is not a problem.  It's the `import WOW from 'wowjs/dist/wow.js';` that's the problem.  I haven't looked at the source code but I'm guessing that this package mentions `window` at the top level of the imported file.

The solution is to use [Dynamic Imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) inside of your `useEffect` so that you are only importing the WOW package when you are in the browser on the client-side.